# How do I create a concatenated altair line chart like the example shown with the below dataframe?

Tags: python, visualization, linechart, altair, stacked-chart

I have the following dataframe:

[Click here to see a picture of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqNZF.png)

And I would like to create a concatenated Altair chart like the one below:

[Concatenated Altair chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79swr.png)

I have this so far but this is not working :

```
alt.Chart(prob_df).alt.Chart(prob_df).mark_line().encode(
    x='Key2',
    y='Year'
).properties(
width=150,
height=150
).facet(
facet='Key1',
columns=3
)
```

What would be the best way to create a graph for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```py
alt.Chart(prob_df).mark_line().encode(
    x='Year',
    y='Prob'
).properties(
    width=150,
    height=150
).facet(
    row='Key1',
    column='Key2'
)
```